# Iterating through list of IEnumerable<MyAbstractClass> resets properties of each item

Tags: c#, foreach, abstract-class, ienumerable

Is there any reason that iterating through an `IEnumerable<AbstractClass>` would reset properties of the each item ?

Imagine that I have a list as items:

```
 public abstract class MyAbstractClass{
  public virtual string ID {get; set;}
 }

public class MyClass : MyAbstractClass {
      public string ID {get; set;}
     }

public static string MyMethod (IEnumerable<MyAbstractClass> items)
{
  //At this moment I can see that items are populated correctly.
  foreach (MyAbstractClass item in items)
  {
    //at this moment each item is kind of reset and all it's properties are null
  }
}
```

any reason why would such thing happen ? I'm not sure if I'm doing anything wrong here.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT :

An I enumerable list of MyClass is passsed to MyMethod.

Comment: You probably want to use an interface instead of an abstract class?

Comment: Well, I suppose it might depend on what your `IEnumerable` is. _Theoretically_, the class implementing it could be _evil_ and alter its items as it iterates though I highly doubt that this is the case in this instance. I think you would need to elaborate: how do you "see that items are populated correctly" before the iteration without iterating? How is it that the item is "kind of reset"? Can you show a sample of the before and after states? EDIT: And also, what type is `items`? Is it a `List<MyAbstractClass>`, or some deferred LINQ-to-objects query, or a database access query?

Comment: I can see the items are populated correctly with the help of break points. I can see that items has true values inside them. I have even tried immediate window when I call ToArray() method of items then the returned array has null values for ID .

Comment: @Ashkan: I think you'll have to post the code as to how you're generating your `items` argument, and ideally, a short program that we can copy/paste and reproduce ourselves.

Comment: I think the more important code is where your IEnumerable is coming from. If it's a LINQ deferred list then what happens in your foreach is that you're getting a 'brand new' iteration of the list, which could be giving you brand new Selected items. If you're going to loop through items before passing them around you may consider casting them into a list or array and making the signature IList instead.

Comment: Adding the override keyword to the derived class's properties did the trick. I still don't understand why. maybe without overriding it was using the properties of the patent class ?!!
@ChrisSinclair : Sorry the code was too complicated and I couldn't really write it here, but thanks anyway ;)

Comment: @Ashkan: Yes, if the parent class's properties were not explicitly overridden by the derived class, then the two properties are considered _completely different_ and not associated with each other whatsoever. Accessing the property when the compile-time type is one or the other will access their own specific property value. Only by overriding it will they essentially be the same shared property.